# Newtonsoft read array in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to get an entry of a json array into a messagebox but i can't seem to get the entry it always gives me

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

No matter what i do here is the json i use:

```
[
 {
  "code": 200,
  "token": "yourtokenhere",
  "id": "youridhere",
  "user": "user",
  "message": "Successfully connected"
 }
]
```

Here is what i got so far:

```
string json = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\zero.json";
login fetch = new login();
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, fetch);
MessageBox.Show(fetch.user);
```

And here is the C# class i made:

```
class login
{
    public string code;
    public string token;
    public string id;
    public string user;
    public string message;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The full code is available [here](http://github.com/kqdi/ZeroDotNet)

Comment: You're trying to deserialize an array into an object. Deserialize an array into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is two-fold.

One issue is that you want to deserialize an array into an object. Other answers here already have addressed this issue.

The other issue, the one responsible for the error in your question, is that you used the *Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.PopulateObject* method incorrectly. Look at its [**documentation**](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_PopulateObject.htm):

> ```
> public static void PopulateObject(
>     string value,
>     Object target
> )
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
> value
>     Type: SystemString
>     The JSON to populate values from.
>
> target
>     Type: SystemObject
>     The target object to populate values onto.
> ```

Note that this method expects the **Json string data** as first argument, *not* a file path!

So what happens in your code is the variable *json* gets assigned a file path to your Json file (`string json = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\zero.json";`). The string variable *json* will now have a content like `@"C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\zero.json"`.

Your code passes this string as json data to the *PopulateObject()* method. But since this string is not json data (it's just the file path), *PopulateObject()* fails. (Note that the error message complains about the json data starting unexpectedly with a `C`.)

One possibility of implementing what you want to do is to first read the Json file content into a string, and then pass this to the Json deserializer (in the same way as demonstrated by the other answers):

```
string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\zero.json";
string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
List<login> fetch = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<login>>(json);
```

Comment: No problemo!. These thing can easily happen and be overlooked. What clued me in first when seeing your question was the error message complaining about that omnious `C` character at the start of the Json data. Then looking at your code example it was clear it was trying to parse a file path string like `C:\.......` as Json. An example of why it is often so helpful to have the complete error message together with the problem description :)

Comment: So i got it to work but now i can't seem to get the id, message etc to show i'm pretty new to json so idk what i should do i tried `login get = new login;` and then use `MessageBox.Show(get.user);` but that shows nothing

Comment: Take a step back. Your problem you are now having has nothing to do with Json (or Json.NET for that matter). You seem to have difficulties grasping basic C# concepts. Look what you do: you create a new (empty) login instance with `login get = new login;`. Then you are going to display the "user" field/property of this new empty login object. What do you expect a new empty login instance contains?

Comment: It's just that i've never done any of this with any of my previous projects and im here to learn also login is a class that i created

Comment: Don't worry. That's precisely why i am doing this kind of 'mental gymnastics' right now with you :-P Did you really understand my last comment about what you actually did with your code?

Comment: I forgot that with the method i used to use i could simply add "get" to it and if i used it then it would work (with objects not arrays) but arrays are a whole diffrent story i don't know how to populate "get" with the deserialized json

Comment: You don't populate "get". Look, what does the deserializer return? What do you get from the Json deserializer? You only need to look at the source code in the answers given here to see it ;)

Comment: I don't understand you clerly got more knowledge than i do all i got now is a button that uses your code and nothing more because i don't know what to do to get the data that the deserializer returns this is my first time working with json.net and json

Comment: Hold on. You think your problem is with Json, but this is not true. Your problem is being unfamiliar with C#/programming. If we were to remove Json from the situation, you would still have the same problem. Let's go back to my last question: What does the function call `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<login>>(json);` return (i.e, what does it give back to your program)? It is spelled out explicitely in the answers here, you just need to look at them...

Comment: I think i'm missing something i read trough it a couple times and can't seem to find it :/ also all i know about C# i got from sololearn and here but thats it

Comment: I suggest you take some time reading some C# tutorial(s) (I cannot say anything about that sololearn stuff, as i don't know it). Focus for now on how to call methods and how to receive return values from a called method. Google for something like "C# tutorial call method return value". There should be plenty of tutorials that explain this in different ways. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Yes, it will take some time reading that stuff, but if you don't know the basics you will have a really, really hard time writing even the simplest program. Especially, wanting to write a program with UI, Json processing and perhaps some more things while not knowing the basics of the programming language/environment (C#/.NET) is just a recipe for endless frustration.

Comment: I will look up some tutorials but i'm really frustrated with not knowing how to display it into a message box but i see i wont get the answer here i will go on to google then and try to find it there

Comment: Just to give you a quick answer to your problem (you still need to spend some good tutorial time, though): The deserializer returns a `List<login>` object (look at the code: `List<login> fetch = ...`) and assigns it to a variable named "fetch". `List<login>` means "a list with *login* objects". (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) This list contains the *login* objects with the data from the json file. To access the first login object in this list (which is also the only login object in the list, since your json data only provides information for one object), you would do something like `fetch[0]`. To display the user of this login object, you could simply do `MessageBox.Show(fetch[0].user);`. But how much does this really teach you?

Comment: Thanks alot i'm watching some tutorials now i'm getting an understandding of it all now

Answer (score 0):

JSON data is an array and you are trying to deserialize it into an object.

Try below code:

```
List<login> fetch = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<login>>(json);
```

Please check 
[JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm)

Comment: I'm not too fimilliar with json this is the firts tim i'm using it sorry i will try your solution

Comment: @Zeq, it's ok. I would be glad if my answer helps you

Comment: It still gives me the same error. I must be doing something wrong thanks anyways!